# Cambiar opacidad a JTextField que esta deshabilitado

Tags: java, poo, java-swing

Quisira saber como hago para que este JTextField que esta con `setEnabled(false);` no se vea como opaco pero que se mantenga desahabilitado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con el método `setDisabledTextColor(Color.black)`

Comment: Bro muchas gracias me funciono